# Print what you see in richtextbox - C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am working on the C# windows form.
I just need to print preview what I see in a richtextbox like we preview a word document before print it.
The richtextbox contains formatted letters and an image.
I tried to get this done but couldn't get through. I think the problem is with the below line of codes.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, new Font(richTextBox1.Font.ToString(), richTextBox1.Font.Size), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 66, 50);
}
```

Can anyone help with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: With this you are just drawing simple string to the output. To print it with all styles inside `richtextbox` you will need to create own code which will take text and styles from richtextbox and then draw strings according to that styles for each part.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not just that one line. You could roll your own RichTextBox dervation as suggested in the comment. If you just want a "print preview" like feature, a relatively easy way would be to convert the RTF format from RichTextBox into html and then use .NET WebBrowser component to display it.

1. Get and install RtfPipe package with NuGet package manager. That lib will know how to convert RTF to HTML.
2. Have a RichTextBox named richTextBox1 and WebBrowser named webBrowser1 on your form.

Then you can do something like this:

```
private void ShowHtml()
{
    string html = RtfPipe.Rtf.ToHtml(richTextBox1.Rtf);
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
}
```

Have not tried that with images but it does handle text formatting.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you.